# 8bpp image too dark

Tags: image-processing, bitmap

I created a viewer for a image which was originally an indexed 8bpp 256-color file. I am reading its color palette in the first place, then the image bytes themselves, which reference to a color in the 256 color palette.

With this data I create a bitmap (32 bpp, but also tried all kinds of 16bpp) and asign each pixel with SetPixel.

The result is the correct image but the colors are too dark.

Any ideas why this might be happening? I suppose the problem lies in the PixelFormat, but how can I fix it?

Comment: The pallete colors were assuming a gamma curve perhaps?

Comment: I would not say so, since what I am doing is translating a Pascal program to .NET. The original program shows the images with the right color, with no further adjustments

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might not scale the byte values of the original colors to the new storage size. Using the 8 bit values straight off in a 16/32 bit environment would indeed make the image very dark, since their values are at most 255, while a 16 or 32 bit value can be considerably larger.

Comment: That would make sense, since using 16bpp format is slightly brighter. How can I scale them?

Comment: Even so, when using SetPixel(int,int, Color), R,G, and B values can only be up to 255. Otherwise I get a runtime error.

Comment: Solved it.

As someone pointed out to me, turns out the problem was on the VGA palette having up to 18 bits per color (6 bit per channel). So I multiplied by 4 and got a good approximation.

Thanks!

PD. Could not post this as a self-answer... posting it as a comment.